# How to prefix numbers with optional letter?

Tags: xtext

I am building on an [initial Xtext project](https://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/documentation/102_domainmodelwalkthrough.html) build using gradle.

```
ext.xtextVersion = '2.20.0'
```

I have following xtext grammar:

```
grammar com.exampe.Rule with org.eclipse.xtext.common.Terminals hidden(WS, ML_COMMENT, SL_COMMENT)

import "http://www.eclipse.org/emf/2002/Ecore" as ecore

generate rule "http://www.example.com/Rule"

Rule:
    {Number} (other?='o')? number=INT
;
```

This does NOT parse `o19`.

Then, the Rule is changed to following:

```
Rule:
    {Number} (other?='*')? number=INT
;
```

This DOES parse `*19`.

I did not find any special treatment in letters versus symbols.

What is going wrong here? How can I make `o19` getting parsed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`o19` is parsed by the rule `ID` which you imported by inheriting from `org.eclipse.xtext.common.Terminals`. In Xtext, the Lexer runs independent from the parser (context insensitive) and tokenizes the text into keywords and terminal rule calls.

You have to add a terminal rule for such cases.

```
terminal PREFIXED_INT:
   'o' INT;
```

But I don't know whether it's a good idea in terms of readability if you keep the `ID` rule as well. Readers of your code might be mislead.